# Docker container runs local, but not on AWS Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created Docker container with flash and gunicorn. I tested it locally successfully and pushed it without any problems to Docker hub. I also have AWS EB CLI installed so I tested it with `eb local run`. Everything worked fine.

I used the following [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker.html) to deploy it on AWS Elastic BeanStalk. When I visit URL of the application,  I am getting `HTTP ERROR 504`. I looked at log file and there are any error messages.

How can I further troubleshoot this issue?